# MVC spring exception

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC. My code used to work but I changed something and it fails now. Unfortunately I can't understand what is wrong in there. This is error that I am getting. Any idea?

```
public class Site {

    private String siteName;
    private String emailFromAddress;
    private String customerServicesEmailAddress;    
    private String googleAnalyticsAccountId;    
    private String doNotReplyEmailAddress;
    private String customerServicesTelephoneNumber;
    private String takeoverCss;
    private String helpUrl;
    private boolean isSubsite;
    private int searchResultsPerPage;
    private List<BlackWord> blackList;
    private List<QueryOverride> listOverrides; 
    ...
  }
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
    Field error in object 'site' on field 'listOverrides': rejected value [9]; codes [typeMismatch.site.listOverrides,typeMismatch.listOverrides,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [site.listOverrides,listOverrides]; arguments []; default message [listOverrides]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'listOverrides'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.company.tabernus.commerce.domain.QueryOverride] for property 'listOverrides[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the most helpful line is this:

> Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.thehutgroup.tabernus.commerce.domain.QueryOverride] for property 'listOverrides[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Spring tries to put a value of type `String` into `listOverrides` but does not know how to convert a `String` into a `QueryOverride`. If you aren't doing anything completely wrong right now, which you can fix to resolve the problem, Spring needs to know how to convert between strings and QueryOverrides (most likely: both directions). You might want to look into [type converters](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) for this.